# Dtrace for Windows client socket program

Tags: dtrace

I want to discover what gets sent between a client program (Windows) to a server program (Windows).

This is using a database called 4DD.
I'm trying to work out the protocol it is using but there is no documentation I can find.

My client program, I assume is using sockets so the client will be like:
socket 
connect (to server)

send
recv

closesocket

I think I should be able to use DTrace for Windows and just get a callback for each of these system calls
and more importantly what it send and what it recv.
I'll be starting the client to be traced first so I'll know it's pid.

Does anyone know how to set up DTRace on Windows to do this?
I know processmonitor can do most of this but it does not show the data - what is sent and what is recv.

Thanks for any help.